# Odoo - Return record lists on form view

Tags: python, odoo

I use Odoo 14 Enterprise.
From a wizard form, I want to return a form view with record list into domain.

If i use tree view, this action is great. But, i want directly show to result into form view.

Can you help me ?

My code :

```
return {
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'views': [(False, 'tree'), (False, 'form')],
    'res_model': 'annual.control.base',
    'domain': [('id', 'in', [174, 175])],
    'target': 'current',
    # 'context': ctx,
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Form views are used to display the data from a single record

Comment: @Kenly 
Thanks. Can't get around the problem? Even with JavaScript?

Comment: I don't get the rationale for "want to directly show ... into form view". Your example has a domain with 2 IDs and there is no lets call it "double form view". Only one record can be shown in the form view of odoo. Do you mean you want the form view of the first record and the pager, to change to the next record(s)? If yes, it's probably possible by adding `'view_mode': 'form,tree'` to your action dictionary. But i'm not sure if odoo is taking this combination or rendering it that way.

Comment: @CZoellner Thank you for your reply. I tried to put 'form,view' but without success. I am building an application and in this application my client does not want a list view. Because quite simply, in a list view, there is information about records that is confidential data. If a company trainee is training alongside a user, he can very well analyze the list view and retrieve information for him to sell.

Answer (score 0):

Change views position

```
return {
'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
'views': [(False, 'form'),(False, 'tree')],
'res_model': 'annual.control.base',
'domain': [('id', 'in', [174, 175])],
'target': 'current',
# 'context': ctx,
```

}

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work!